# Grouping indices of unique elements in numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have many large (>100,000,000) lists of integers that contain many duplicates. I want to get the indices where each of the element occur. Currently I am doing something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

a = np.array([1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2])
d=defaultdict(list)
for i,e in enumerate(a):
    d[e].append(i)

d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0], 2: [1, 4, 6], 3: [5], 4: [3], 6: [2]})
```

This method of iterating through each element is time consuming. Is there a efficient or vectorized way to do this?

**Edit1**
I tried the methods of Acorbe and Jaime on the following

```
a = np.random.randint(2000, size=10000000)
```

The results are

```
original: 5.01767015457 secs
Acorbe: 6.11163902283 secs
Jaime: 3.79637312889 secs
```

Comment: i think multi processing ur fuction will solve ur problem..https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is very similar to what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159791/find-the-indices-of-non-zero-elements-and-group-by-values), so what follows is an adaptation of my answer there. The simplest way to vectorize this is to use sorting. The following code borrows a lot from the implementation of `np.unique` for the upcoming version 1.9, which includes unique item counting functionality, see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L93):

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2])
>>> sort_idx = np.argsort(a)
>>> a_sorted = a[idx]
>>> unq_first = np.concatenate(([True], a_sorted[1:] != a_sorted[:-1]))
>>> unq_items = a_sorted[unq_first]
>>> unq_count = np.diff(np.nonzero(unq_first)[0])
```

and now:

```
>>> unq_items
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
>>> unq_count
array([1, 3, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

To get the positional indices for each values, we simply do:

```
>>> unq_idx = np.split(sort_idx, np.cumsum(unq_count))
>>> unq_idx
[array([0], dtype=int64), array([1, 4, 6], dtype=int64), array([5], dtype=int64),
 array([3], dtype=int64), array([2], dtype=int64)]
```

And you can now construct your dictionary zipping `unq_items` and `unq_idx`.

Note that `unq_count` doesn't count the occurrences of the last unique item, because that is not needed to split the index array. If you wanted to have all the values you could do:

```
>>> unq_count = np.diff(np.concatenate(np.nonzero(unq_first) + ([a.size],)))
>>> unq_idx = np.split(sort_idx, np.cumsum(unq_count[:-1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def to_components(index):
    return np.split(np.argsort(index), np.cumsum(np.unique(index, return_counts=True)[1]))
```

Comment: Looks like the most concise solution and with commonly used `numpy` functions

Comment: Please add `np.cumsum(...)[:-1]` to your answer to remove the last empty group. `np.split(...)[:-1]` would also work

Answer (score 2):

this can be solved via [python pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (python data analysis library) and a `DataFrame.groupby` call.

Consider the following

```
 a = np.array([1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2])

 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a})

 gg = df.groupby(by=df.a)
 gg.groups
```

output

```
 {1: [0], 2: [1, 4, 6], 3: [5], 4: [3], 6: [2]}
```

Comment: I have never used panda. Is this faster than pure python version.

Comment: @imsc, AFAIK it is based on numpy for what concerns data types and implements cython and pure C methods for speed. I regularly and happily use it for large dataset (~10M records).

Comment: Thanks, I will test it and let you know.

Comment: With 10 million random integers in the range `[0,20]`, on my machine at least, the pandas method takes 5.27s vs 5.86 s for the OP's method if `a` is a np.ndarray. If `a` is a standard python list, then pandas takes 7.85 s, whereas the original method takes 4.05 s.

Comment: @JoshAdel, that's due to the fact that an intermediate conversion to np.ndarray is performed by pandas. I guess.

Comment: FYI: 10k items `np.ndarray` of 1k different integers: @Jamie's pure `numpy` method is fastest, @Denis Shcheglov's way is 20% slower (probably because you do the sorting twice (`argsort` + `unique`). `pandas` is 20x slower. Same seed for random generator, tested with `timeit` (numpy 1.16.2, pandas 0.24.2)

Answer (score 2):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) implements a solution inspired by Jaime's; but with tests, a nice interface, and a lot of related functionality:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique, idx_groups = npi.group_by(a, np.arange(len(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and quick solution.

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4])
sort_idx = np.argsort(a)
unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
b = {key: sort_idx[sum(counts[:key]): sum(counts[:key]) + counts[key]] for key in unique}
```

Comment: This is a nice cumulative sum : any reason you did not simply use the `numpy.cumsum` ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was recently working on a similar thing where performance is critical and so I experimented extensively with timing. I hope my findings will be beneficial to the community.

[Jaime's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23271510/14737723) based on `np.unique` is the fastest algorithm possible in Python, but with one caveat: the indices are **not ordered** (because numpy uses `quicksort` [by default](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)) and the result is different from OP's original algorithm (called hereafter *naive*). Using the `stable` option fixes it, but it slows things down a bit.

The naive method can be improved using Python's built-in `array` module like this:

```
import array
from collections import defaultdict

a = np.array(...)  # 1D, int array
d = defaultdict(lambda: array.array("L"))
alist = array.array("L")
alist.frombytes(a.tobytes())
for n in range(len(alist)):
    d[alist[n]].append(n)
```

It's just fractions slower than Jaime's solution with stable sort.

Here's some testing done on my platform with Python 3

```
Best of 5
Naive method: 0.21274029999999988 s
Naive improved: 0.13265090000000002 s
Unique quick: 0.073496 s
Unique stable: 0.1235801999999997 s
```

The results from the naive method, naive improved, and unique stable are dictionaries with sorted lists of indices. Indices from unique quick are not sorted.

The benchmark code

```
import array
import timeit
from collections import defaultdict

import numpy as np

def count_naive(a):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for n, e in enumerate(a):
        d[e].append(n)
    return dict(d)

def count_improved(a):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: array.array("L"))
    alist = array.array("L")
    alist.frombytes(a.tobytes())
    for n in range(len(alist)):
        d[alist[n]].append(n)
    return {n: indices.tolist() for n, indices in d.items()}

def count_unique(a):
    sorted_idx = np.argsort(a)  # , kind='stable')
    counts = np.bincount(a)
    split_idx = np.split(sorted_idx, np.cumsum(counts[:-1]))
    return {n: indices.tolist() for n, indices in enumerate(split_idx)}

def count_stable(a):
    sorted_idx = np.argsort(a, kind="stable")
    counts = np.bincount(a)
    split_idx = np.split(sorted_idx, np.cumsum(counts[:-1]))
    return {n: indices.tolist() for n, indices in enumerate(split_idx)}

a = np.random.randint(1000, size=1000000)

trials = 5
t_naive = timeit.repeat("count_naive(a)", globals=globals(), repeat=trials, number=1)
t_improved = timeit.repeat("count_improved(a)", globals=globals(), repeat=trials, number=1)
t_unique = timeit.repeat("count_unique(a)", globals=globals(), repeat=trials, number=1)
t_stable = timeit.repeat("count_stable(a)", globals=globals(), repeat=trials, number=1)

print(f"Best of {trials}")
print(f"Naive method: {min(t_naive)} s")
print(f"Naive improved: {min(t_improved)} s")
print(f"Unique quick: {min(t_unique)} s")
print(f"Unique stable: {min(t_stable)} s")
```

N.B. All functions are written in a way that they all return `Dict[int, list]` so the results can be directly compared.